# Can't find the XIB File for RootViewController in Mobile SDK iOS Project

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

How do I modify the UI of my app. I see that there is no xib associated with `RootViewController`

I am use Mobile SDK 3.0 for native iOS app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design because the `RootViewController` inherits from `UITableViewController` and uses the `SFRestDelegate`

Whatever UI elements you want to have in your app should be defined in the viewDidLoad() method

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Create all your UI elements here
    self.thumbnailCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}
```

If you want to modify the default TableView look and feel, you can get the cell reference and change things accordingly. For example

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell

NSDictionary *obj = [dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *fileId = obj[@"id"];
// Set cell propertiers and UI now
// cell.xxx
```